# Connect two PCs to Azure vnet then RDP from one to the other

Tags: azure, vpn

I have an Azure vnet setup, to which two PCs are connected via a point-to-site VPN. I was hoping to be able to then RDP from one pc to the other using the IP assigned by the gateway, but this doesn't work, just can't find the other pc. I've dropped firewalls etc... to test this, but still nothing.

Can anyone advise if this is actually possible, or if there is something else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this partially by updating the routes.txt file in the installation folder for the client app by adding an entry for the subnet used by the gateway to assign IP address to new logins.

While this now routes to the correct PC when RDPing, unfortunately a new IP is assigned to the PC every time it connects to the VPN, making it difficult to know the IP address when connecting.